# CString, Datetime and other special fields in boost interprocess

Tags: c++, sql-server, boost, interface, boost-interprocess

at the moment I try to set up an project with boost interprocess. The goal is to hold a table permanent available. The table hast around 30 Milion rows and it takes to long to import the data in every single programm that needs the data.

The data I want to provide is from an MSSQL database and has different fieldtypes like *bit*, *int*, *nvarchar(5)* or *datetime*.

In our current programms we import *nvarchar(5)* as CString and *datetime* as TIMESTAMP_STRUCT. When setting up my project I could not find a way to put a CString or a TIMESTAMP_STRUCT in the shared memory because there are no containers provided.

Please find a minimal example below:

```
#include <afxdb.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <string>



using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main()
{
    //Teststruct to test shared memory
    struct Teststruct
    {
        int ID;
        string name;
        int Price;
    };

    //Testdata to test shared memory
    Teststruct Testdata;
    Testdata.ID = 1;
    Testdata.name = "NAME";
    Testdata.Price = 10;

    typedef allocator<Teststruct, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  SharedMemAllo;
    typedef vector<Teststruct, SharedMemAllo> MyVector;

    //delete SharedMem if already existing
    shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
    //create SharedMem with given size
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 1000);

    const SharedMemAllo alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());

    MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  //Insert data in the vector
    {
        Testdata.ID = i;
        myvector->push_back(Testdata);
    }

    return 0;
};
```

I am looking for a possability to use the struct Testdata2 (below) and hold CStrings and
and TIMESTAMP_STRUCTs in my shared memory as well. In this case we would not have to change all programms that are working with CString.

```
struct Teststruct_2
{
    int ID;
    CString name;
    int Price;
    TIMESTAMP_STRUCT date;
};
```

Do you know any way to solve this problem?

Best regards